# pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be specified manually.;'

Tags: csv, file, apache-spark, pyspark, schema

I tried both these:

```
spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("s3://...")

spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("s3://...")
```

Is there a way to read the schema during runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that:

- Is it a valid CSV?If so, does it have header?
- File is not corrupted
- Maybe the schema in CSV is not correct
- Maybe the delimiter is not comma, if it is not comma, you need to specify the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

I changed file name and the error was gone.

Bad name: `_test.csv`
Good name: `test.csv`