# Not able to create table from CSV in Databricks

Tags: python, sql, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to create a table from a CSV file stored in Azure Storage Account. I am using the below code. I am using Azure Databricks. Notebook is in Python.

```
%sql
drop table if exists customer;
create table customer
using csv 
options ( path "/mnt/datalake/data/Customer.csv", header "True", mode "FAILFAST", inferSchema "True");
```

I am getting the below error.

**Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be specified manually.**

Anyone having any idea, on how to resolve this error.

Comment: As per the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70802177/pyspark-sql-utils-analysisexception-unable-to-infer-schema-for-csv-it-must-be Please check if the file is valid or not. If you are sure the file is valid, try reading it by passing the schema as shown in the link https://docs.databricks.com/external-data/csv.html#read-csv-files-with-schema-notebook - Sharing the structure of the csv file might help....

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced above and got the below results.

This my csv file in `data` container.

[image]

This is my mounting:

[image]

I have mounted this and when I tried to create table from CSV file, I got same error.

[image]

The above error arises when we don't give correct path in the csv file. In file path after `/mnt` give mount point(here `onemount` for me) not container name as we already mounted till container.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that you need to take the Spark API format path instead of file API format path, which is exactly your mistake in the provided code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34579928)